# Daily copy of production database to another server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I would like a way to automatically and completely recreate every night a certain database (used by the support team to reproduce bug reports) with a copy of the production database. The production server in Azure SQL has multiple databases.

I thought about using an Azure Automation runbook to do this everyday at 03:00 AM.

I have two options, but each one has its own problems.

- **Copy the databases to a new server**: Good, it is transactionally consistent and all, but I would like the copy to have very little hardware, reducing costs by using cheaper tiers, and when I copy via `az sql db copy`, for example, it is impossible to use different hardware than the original production database. Having databases with the same tier and hardware as production would be expensive and a waste;
- **Export a BACPAC into Blob Storage then import/restore**: It is simply not transactionally consistent. Maybe it wouldn't cause any problems, because the exports would run in the early hours of the morning, when traffic is minimal and the copy DB would only be used by support to reproduce bugs, etc.

I've also read about some data sync and replication group solutions, but they sound expensive (or maybe they are not, I am new to Azure and Microsoft SQL solutions, past experiences were with another cloud providers and DBMSs, so concepts may differ). Also, solutions around data sync and replication don't recreate the database every time, they just keep in sync when I prefer clean copies.

So, how could I solve this issue and empower the support team to have their desired environment without it being unnecessarily expensive?

Also, as a side thought, considering cost, would it be cheaper to run this copy within AKS alongside the application or is Azure SQL the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ARM template for that, and it will allow you to specify the service tier of the database on the destination server.

A sample template could be:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "administratorLogin": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "administratorLoginPassword": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "administrators": {
        "type": "object",
        "defaultValue": {}
    },
    "databaseName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "serverName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "createMode": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "sourceDatabaseId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "skuName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "tier": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "zoneRedundant": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": false
    },
    "licenseType": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "readScaleOut": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Disabled"
    },
    "numberOfReplicas": {
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 0
    },
    "minCapacity": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "autoPauseDelay": {
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 0
    },
    "enableADS": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": false
    },
    "allowAzureIps": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": true
    },
    "useVAManagedIdentity": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": false,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "To enable vulnerability assessments, the user deploying this template must have an administrator or owner permissions."
        }
    },
    "vaStoragelessEnabled": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": false,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Flag for enabling vulnerability assessments with express configuration (storage less), the user deploying this template must have administrator or owner permissions."
        }
    },
    "enableVA": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": false
    },
    "requestedBackupStorageRedundancy": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "maintenanceConfigurationId": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "secondaryType": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "databaseIdentity": {
        "type": "object",
        "defaultValue": {}
    },
    "databaseFederatedClientId": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": ""
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "condition": "[parameters('enableVA')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
        "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
            "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
            "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": "true",
            "allowBlobPublicAccess": "false"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "condition": "[parameters('useVAManagedIdentity')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
                "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
                "name": "[concat(variables('storageName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', variables('uniqueRoleGuid') )]",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('StorageBlobContributor')]",
                    "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName')), '2018-06-01-preview', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                    "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]",
                    "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01-preview",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
        "properties": {
            "version": "12.0",
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]"
        },
        "identity": "[if(and(parameters('enableVA'),parameters('useVAManagedIdentity')), json('{\"type\":\"SystemAssigned\"}'), json('null'))]",
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2022-08-01-preview",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                ],
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "name": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
                "properties": {
                    "createMode": "[parameters('createMode')]",
                    "secondaryType": "[parameters('secondaryType')]",
                    "sourceDatabaseId": "[parameters('sourceDatabaseId')]",
                    "zoneRedundant": "[parameters('zoneRedundant')]",
                    "licenseType": "[parameters('licenseType')]",
                    "readScale": "[parameters('readScaleOut')]",
                    "highAvailabilityReplicaCount": "[parameters('numberOfReplicas')]",
                    "minCapacity": "[parameters('minCapacity')]",
                    "autoPauseDelay": "[parameters('autoPauseDelay')]",
                    "requestedBackupStorageRedundancy": "[parameters('requestedBackupStorageRedundancy')]",
                    "federatedClientId": "[parameters('databaseFederatedClientId')]"
                },
                "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
                    "tier": "[parameters('tier')]"
                },
                "type": "databases",
                "identity": "[parameters('databaseIdentity')]"
            },
            {
                "condition": "[parameters('allowAzureIps')]",
                "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                ],
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                "properties": {
                    "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                    "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                },
                "type": "firewallrules"
            },
            {
                "condition": "[parameters('enableADS')]",
                "type": "advancedThreatProtectionSettings",
                "apiVersion": "2021-11-01-preview",
                "name": "Default",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]",
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/', parameters('databaseName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "state": "Enabled"
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "[parameters('enableVA')]",
                "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
                "type": "vulnerabilityAssessments",
                "name": "Default",
                "properties": {
                    "storageContainerPath": "[if(parameters('enableVA'), concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))).primaryEndpoints.blob, 'vulnerability-assessment'), '')]",
                    "storageAccountAccessKey": "[if(and(parameters('enableVA'),not(parameters('useVAManagedIdentity'))), listKeys(variables('storageName'), '2018-02-01').keys[0].value, '')]",
                    "recurringScans": {
                        "isEnabled": true,
                        "emailSubscriptionAdmins": false,
                        "emails": []
                    }
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]",
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageName'))]",
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/advancedThreatProtectionSettings/Default')]"
                ]
            },
            {
                "condition": "[parameters('vaStoragelessEnabled')]",
                "type": "sqlVulnerabilityAssessments",
                "apiVersion": "2022-02-01-preview",
                "name": "Default",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "state": "Enabled"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
    }
],
"variables": {
    "subscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
    "resourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
    "uniqueStorage": "[uniqueString(variables('subscriptionId'), variables('resourceGroupName'), parameters('location'))]",
    "storageName": "[tolower(concat('sqlva', variables('uniqueStorage')))]",
    "uniqueRoleGuid": "[guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName')), variables('storageBlobContributor'), resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName')))]",
    "StorageBlobContributor": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'baxxxxx4-2xx1-4xxd-ax3-e9xxxxxxxxfe')]"
}
```

}

The parameters for the template can be provided as follows.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "databaseName": {
            "value": "AdventureWorksLT_2023-11-07T12-47Z_Copy"
        },
        "serverName": {
            "value": "morillodestinationserver"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "eastus"
        },
        "createMode": {
            "value": "Copy"
        },
        "sourceDatabaseId": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/47804548-af19-4e18-b91f-4be21ff02a7d/resourceGroups/rgStackOverflowforums/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/morillo/databases/AdventureWorksLT_2023-11-07T12-47Z"
        },
        "skuName": {
            "value": "S2"
        },
        "tier": {
            "value": "Standard"
        },
        "zoneRedundant": {
            "value": false
        },
        "licenseType": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "readScaleOut": {
            "value": "Disabled"
        },
        "numberOfReplicas": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "autoPauseDelay": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "enableADS": {
            "value": false
        },
        "enableVA": {
            "value": false
        },
        "vaStoragelessEnabled": {
            "value": false
        },
        "useVAManagedIdentity": {
            "value": false
        },
        "allowAzureIps": {
            "value": true
        },
        "requestedBackupStorageRedundancy": {
            "value": "Local"
        },
        "databaseIdentity": {
            "value": {
                "type": "None"
            }
        },
        "databaseFederatedClientId": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "administratorLogin": {
            "value": "adminlogin"
        },
        "administratorLoginPassword": {
            "value": Your$trongPassw0rd
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-cli#deploy-resources-by-using-an-arm-template-or-bicep-file) or PowerShell to deploy the template whenever you want. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook) you can find also how to automate the deployment of an ARM template using Azure Automation.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. So I would be able to, for example, copy a database with Basic tier into a new one with Standard (or even Serverless) tier?

Comment: Also, one more thing, do you know if Terraform could do this just like ARM templates can? Or maybe Pulumi running on a Python-based environment of Azure Automation. Terraform resource for azurerm_sql_database seems to have the same parameters as the ARM template.

Comment: About your first question, you are correct.

Comment: About Terraform, I have use it to create new infrastructure and modify existent one, but I don't know how to copy an Azure SQL to another logivcal server using Terraform, I would need to try it.

Comment: If I run this template daily and the copied database already exist from yesterday, I would need to delete/clean the copied database before running the template or the copy creation would automatically recreate everything?

Comment: You will have to drop the existent database using the name specified by the template first, then deploy the template, The same with importing a bacpac, it will always create a new database, and if you need to restore with the same name of an existing database, you need to drop the existent database first.

Comment: I noticed that source databases with tier Standard are copying alright, but the ones with Basic tier are failing to copy. My template always sets tier to "GeneralPurpose" and skuName to "GP_S_Gen5_1".

When the source database is of Basic tier, it fails with: 
The tier 'Basic' does not support the sku 'SQLDB_GP_S_Gen5_1'

Comment: You are correct. When you copy a DTU Basic database using ARM Templates you are allowed only to copy it as Basic and nothing else. You are copying it looking for a cheap service tier, and basic is only 5 dollars a month. You can copy it and then scale it to vCore as a workaround.

Comment: Great. Thanks for everything. One last question: If I change the tier and specs right after copying, how much of the tier I was in before switching would I pay? For example, I copy a Basic tier database, then I switch to serverless right after, how much time of Basic tier would be charged?

Comment: You are always welcome. You will be charge 1 hour of Basic tier = US$ 0.0067.